# Java "exception in thread "main"" error fix

Tags: java, bounds, out

Currently I am working on a application which allows technical manuals to be added, stored, borrowed, returned to a virtual library.

Currently I am working on the section which allows the user to return a book they have previously borrowed. When they enter "4" at the main menu they will be displayed with a list of the currently borrowed manuals.

I have managed to get the borrowed manuals to display but I am also met with an error which quits my java application, shown here:

[image]

Here is the relevant code for this application (if I need to display more please let me know):

```
static void returnManual(){
    System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently out on loan:\n\n");
    if(ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) && borrowedManuals.size() >= ManualChoice){
    for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual());
        returnManualTitle = Console.readString(Messages.enterManualTitle, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    }
```

If anyone knows how this error can be resolved please let me know :) I am fairly new to Java!

---

### UPDATE

I have applied the Christophers suggestion made in the comments to change ManualList.size() to borrowedManuals.size().

The issue now is that if the user borrows 2 manuals and wishes to return the second manual, their title entry is not activated once they enter the title name for the (second) manual they wish to return. If the first manual title is entered, the application functions as expected and returns the manual to the library.

Below is an example of this. I have also updated my code (above) to include the changes made.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `ManualList` and `borrowedManuals` have the same size?

Comment: Why are you using ManualList.size() and not borrowedManuals.size()?  You are trying to access the third element in a list that only has 2 elements. (Index of 2 means the 3rd element since it starts at 0)

Comment: Also, don't name variables/fields with an initial capital. The convention is lowercase initial for fields and variables, uppercase first initial for class names. It confuses code coloring and makes your code less readable.

Comment: @ChristopherShannnon thanks for your reply, I have implemented your suggestions and updated my answer with a new issue which occurs

Comment: Yo ushould not change your question from one topic to the other. The index out of bounds is fixed, so open a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(null != ManualList && ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice &&
          ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) ){
for (int i = 0; i < ManualList.size(); i++)
    if(borrowedManuals.size() > i)  // check borrowedManuals size its better to check this in if where you check for ManualList 
       System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual());
       returnManualTitle = Console.readString(Messages.enterManualTitle, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    }
 }
```

First check `ManualList` is not `null` then check `ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice` `ManualList` size is greater then `ManualChoice` then get the value from that index so it will not give you `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: Hmm, this seems to only display 1 borrowed manual, even if the user has borrowed several. Do you know why this is happening? Also, once the user enters the title for the 1 manual shown, the next manual they have borrowed is displayed.

Comment: check size of `borrowedManuals` list, I think you have only one item in this list